# How can I add a price to each of the items in NSObject?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know how I could add a price for each of the items in the given nsobject and display it in a table. much appreciated :)

```
class MenuItems:NSObject{
var sections:[String] = []
var items:[[String]] = []
var price: [[String]] = []


func addSection(section: String, item:[String]){
    sections = sections + [section]
    items = items + [item]

}
}

class AnnMenuItems: MenuItems {
override init() {
    super.init()
    addSection("Threading", item: ["Eye Brows","Upper Lip","Forehead","Chin","Sides","Face Waxing/Face Threading"])
    addSection("Hair", item: ["Rebonding","Hair Dye","Head Massage","Streaking","Hair Cut","Straight Cut","Children Cut","Step Cut","Layer Cut"])
    addSection("Waxing", item: ["Full Arms","3/4 Arms","Under Arms","Full Legs", "3/4 Legs","Half Legs"])
    addSection("Hair Treatments", item: ["Hair Spa","Dandruff","Hair Fall Treatment","Galvanic Treatment", "Hair Wash","Colour/Henna/Oil"])
    addSection("Facial", item: ["Clean Up Normal","Black Heads","Clean Up Special","Herbal Facial", "Fruit Facial"])`


}
}
```

Comment: I suggess u should research on how to create object class effectively....1 object should contain of name,price,category,...etc, not making array for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary in which item-name can be the key and its price can be the value.

Based on your design, you can have other options as well. For example: You can create a struct/class named `Item` and add properties such as `name`, `price`.

Not sure how you want to display, but you can use [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/) to display a list of items along with its price.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tj3n suggested, you should have a finer granularity in your data structures. I'm not sure why you want to use `NSObject` subclasses - I would prefer `struct`s -  but in either case you could do something like this...

```
struct MenuItem {
    var item: String
    var price: String
}
struct MenuSection {
    var sectionName: String
    var items: [MenuItem]
}
struct MenuItems {
    var sections:[MenuSection] = []

    mutating func addSection(section: String, items:[MenuItem]){
        let newSection = MenuSection(sectionName: section, items: items)
        self.sections.append(newSection)
    }
}
func defaultMenu() -> MenuItems {
    var mi = MenuItems()
    mi.addSection("Threading", items: [MenuItem(item: "Eye Brows", price: "10/6d"), MenuItem(item: "Upper Lip", price: "€1") /* etc. */])
    mi.addSection("Hair", items: [MenuItem(item: "Rebonding", price: "$1"), MenuItem(item: "Hair Dye", price: "free") /* etc. */])
    // etc...

    return mi
}
```